# Взять определенный элемент из списка в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

```py
a = [[10, 20, 30], [13223, 56, 48996], [156, 684, 9686]]
print(a[:][1])
```

Выдаст: `[13223, 56, 48996]`

Нужно: `[20, 56, 684]`

То есть, выбрать первый элемент из всех списков максимально быстрым способом. И как это можно реализовать для numpy array?

Comment: print(list(map(lambda x: x[1], a)))

Comment: *И как это можно реализовать для numpy array?* a - это numpy array? `a[:, 1]`

Comment: вы определитесь, это у вас питоновские списки или массивы numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

есть еще способ:

```
a = [[10, 20, 30], [13223, 56, 48996], [156, 684, 9686]]

list(zip(*a))[1]  # (20, 56, 684)
```

если вложенные списки могут быть разной длины, то вместо zip берем zip_longest из библиотеки itertools

Answer (score 1):

Я не эксперт, умею только костыльные решения делать, поэтому такой и предлагаю:

```
a = [[10, 20, 30], [13223, 56, 48996], [156, 684, 9686]]
n = 0
for i in range(3):
    print(a[n][1])
    n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions вам поможет

```py
def take_items_by_index(list_, index_):
    return [i[index_] for i in list_]
```

Пример

```py
a = [[10, 20, 30], [13223, 56, 48996], [156, 684, 9686]]
take_items_by_index(a, 0)
# OUT 
# [10, 13223, 156]
take_items_by_index(a, 1) 
# OUT 
# [20, 56, 684]
take_items_by_index(a, 2) 
# OUT 
# [30, 48996, 9686]
```